# Cron job is not working properly in cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have setup cron job, it is working properly, however when i directly runs the php file(from the path/url) it successfully runs, but from cron its not. However i set another very simple file to make sure my cron command/path is set correctly i created another file and used simple php mail function and its is running successfully. Kindly suggest me the possible areas to look into it.  (I am using Cpanel)

Comment: Do you have some relative paths in php code that you want to run via cron, maybe some includes?

Comment: can you post your complete command from cron job ?

Comment: Try running PHP file using Console (like putty) and check there are any errors. Problem could be on include() or require() file paths.

Comment: @DušanRadojević yes i do have included some files

Comment: if you have relative paths as Dusan mentioned that it is best way to call your script in cronjob via http with curl. This should solve your problem.
curl http ://www.example.com/phpscript.php > /dev/null

Comment: @alan978 can you please give me some examples, how to achieve cronjob via http with curl? should change cronjob path or path of included files?

Comment: instead of putting in cronjob command like php -f /path_to_script/script.php, put command like this "curl http: //domain.com/yourscript.php" (without double quotes)

Comment: @alan978 so my current path is `/usr/local/php4/bin/php /home/serverusername/public_html/test_cron/readmails.php` should i change it to `curl http://mydomain.com/test_cron/readmails.php` ?

Comment: Yes, and if you don't want output than you can add > /dev/null at the end. 
So complete command should be:
curl http: //mydomain.com/test_cron/readmails.php > /dev/null

Comment: thanks @alan978 it works as you said, please post is as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Then anyone with the URL can run your cron - using curl is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of putting in cronjob command like

```
php -f /path_to_script/script.php
```

put command like this:

```
curl http://domain.com/yourscript.php
```

if you want to suppress output you can add `> /dev/null` at the end.

So full command would be:

```
curl http://domain.com/yourscript.php > /dev/null
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Finally ! This is the only working answer I found, thanks a lot, great idea

Comment: It may not work with addon domains though (use absolute path to make it work there).

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to cURL, you can call your script through text-based browser. Something like this:

```
lynx -dump http://localhost/script.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. I am using task scheduling in laravel project on cpanel. My command was

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/user_name/public_html/path/to/cron/script`

It is a version issue. My server default php version is 7.1.33 but in my project the php version is 7.2. So, when i run the schedule command it takes the php7.1 which is not compatible with my projecct. So, according to cpanel documentaions the command is actually for different php version

`/usr/local/bin/ea-php99 /home/shadhinapp/domain_path/path/to/cron/script`.

Any my cron job command is:

`/usr/local/bin/ea-php72 /home/user_name/path_to_your_project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any relative paths -- this includes both files *and commands*.  For example, you shouldn't call just `cp` if you want to copy a file, but something like `/bin/cp` with the *full path* to the command.  To find out the full path, you can run `which <cmd>` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://mydomain/auto_push/task.php?p=1
```

This is live working code from my project. See the image below:

[image]